# save randomForest prediction as vector

Tags: r

I estimate a randomForest, then run the `randomForest.predict` function on some hold-out data.

What I would like to do is (preferably) append the prediction for each row to the dataframe containing the holdout data as a new column, or (second choice) save the (row number in test data, prediction for that row) as a .csv file.

What I can't do is access the internals of the results object in a way that lets me do that.  I'm new to R so I appreciate your help.

I have:

```
    res <-predict(forest_tst1, 
                  test_d,
                  type="response")
```

which successfully gives me a bunch of predictions.

The following is not valid R, but ideally I would do something like:

```
test_d$predicted_value <- results[some_field_of_the_results]
```

or,

```
for i = 1:nrow(test_d)
    test_d[i, new_column] = results[prediction_for_row_i]
end
```

Basically I just want a column of predicted 1's or 0's corresponding to rows in test_d.   I've been trying to use the following commands to get at the internals of the `res` object, but I've not found anything that's helped me.

```
attributes(res)
names(res)
```

Finally - I'm a bit confused by the following if anyone can explain!

```
typeof(res) = "integer"
```

Edit: I *can* do

```
res != test_d$gold_label
```

which is if anything a little confusing, because I'm comparing a column and a non-column object (??), and

```
length(res) = 2053
```

and `res` appears to be indexable

```
attributes(res[1])
$names
[1] "6836"

$levels
[1] "0" "1"

$class
[1] "factor"
```

but I can't select out the sub-parts in a sensible way

```
> res[1][1]
6836 
   0 
Levels: 0 1

> res[1]["levels"]
<NA> 
<NA> 
Levels: 0 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand right, all you are trying to do is add predictions to your Test Data?

```
ind <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.8, 0.2)) 
TestData = iris[ind == 2,] ## Generate Test Data
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris[ind == 1,]) ## Build Model
iris.pred <- predict(iris.rf, iris[ind == 2,]) ## Get Predictions
TestData$Predictions <- iris.pred ## Append the Predictions Column

OutPut:
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Predictions
9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa      setosa
16           5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa      setosa
17           5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4     setosa      setosa
32           5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4     setosa      setosa
42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa      setosa
46           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa      setosa
```

Comment: Works for me.  Thanks a lot!